# Hacer un programa que pase de Int a String

Tags: c++

Hacer un programa que pase `int = 123` a un `string = "123"`

Hice un programa que lo hace con el `stringstream`, pero ahora me piden que lo haga sin eso, con puros ciclos, lo intenté hacer así:

```
Cout<<"datos: ";
Cin>>datos;
Texto = datos;
```

Pero no es válido, lo piden con ciclos, he buscado y no encuentro algo,¿alguna sugerencia?

También si hago:

```
texto+=datos;
```

Me trae el símbolo ascii y no es lo que quiero, estoy atorado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un string no es más que una secuencia de caracteres ASCII. Lo que tienes que hacer es convertir cada dígito numérico en su representación ASCII.

Para un dígito la operación es sencilla:

```
char cuatro = 4 + '0';
```

No hay que olvidar que `char` realmente almacena un número en un byte, luego las operaciones aritméticas están permitidas.

Ahora bien... ¿Cómo se convierte la cadena completa? Cómo te he dicho debes ir recuperando dígito a dígito para aplicar la transformación. Esto lo puedes conseguir dividiendo el número entre 10.

Para saber cuantos dígitos tiene el número puedes usar los logaritmos:

```
int numDigitos = log10(4567)+1;
std::cout << numDigitos;
```

Con ese dato ya puedes saber cuántas iteraciones necesitas:

```
int numero = 4567;
for(; numDigitos > 0; numDigitos--)
{
  int digito = numero % 10;
  numero /= 10;
  std::cout << digito;
}
```

Vaya, resulta que los dígitos se recuperan al revés, del menos significativo al más significativo... Realmente es algo que se puede solucionar fácilmente. Puedes aplicar recursividad o invertir la cadena final para obtener el string final... Aunque dado que ya tienes el número de dígitos calculado puedes usar ese dato para hacer la corrección:

```
char cadena[5] = {0};
int numero = 4567;
for(; numDigitos > 0; numDigitos--)
{
  cadena[numDigitos] = numero % 10;
  numero /= 10;
}
std::cout << cadena;
```

Queda en tu mano adaptarlo a tu ejercicio y usar `std::string` en vez de `char[]`.

Comment: me imagino que usted no empleo algo asi `#include <string> std::string s = std::to_string(100);` bansandose en la pegunta en cuestion de OP, por eso me pregunto si no seria mejor cambiar el titulo de la pregunta pues si alguien nuevo o no tan nuevo busca algo similar al titulo se puede encontrar con estas repuestas y si no lee antentamente la pregunta quizas piense "que jaleo para hacer una convercion".Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Al leer la pregunta es cuando ves que no se puede usar esa función de conversión. No sé si sería necesario mejorar el título, pero estoy desde el móvil y ya me ha costado escribir la respuesta

Comment: pienso que tiene un error aqui -> `char cadena[5] = 0;` faltan los `{ }` despues en los ejemplo que pone al final le falta añadir -> `int numDigitos = log10(4567)+1;` pues los llama desde el for, y cuando dice log10 no indica si es de una libreria o es una funcion que tiene que crear, con lo que si el OP copia su codigo igual piensa que no funciona, yo cuando escribo cosas asi suelo poner tomelo como psudocode, si quiere se lo adapto yo en lo que le comente. Saludos P.D: los errores probablemente sera por lo que comenta del movil solo se lo digo asi igual le es mas facil cambiarlos.

Comment: @AngelAngel la inicializacion efectivamente está mal (es un coñazo poner las llaves con el movil), lo que dices de `numDigitos` no lo he añadido porque era algo que ya había explicado en el párrafo anterior y la idea es explicar las diferentes partes que permiten hacer la conversión... no plantarle la solución literal puesto que tampoco ha expuesto código por su parte.

Comment: Todo está perfecto, pero a la hora de pasarlo al string me guarda los valores en su símbolo ascii, no me guarda los datos como tal, el problema dice que no puedo usar el std:: ni el stringstream ni ninguna función ya creada para eso, al guardar el número 1 me trae una cara, el 2 el círculo, etc. Ya intenté de todo y no logro guardar.

Comment: @JoseLuis Con esas restricciones te están pidiendo que te curres tu el algoritmo, no que no puedas usar `std::cout` para sacar el resultado por pantalla. Te dicen simplemente que no puedes hacer uso de ninguna utilidad que haga la operación por tí (`stringstream` puede convertir entero a `string`, `to_string` y `sprintf` lo mismo...)

Answer (score 4):

Una alternativa es dividir y obtener digito por digito del numero que quieres convertir a string, cada vez que obtengas un digito le suma 48 en decimal o 0x30 en hexadecimal para convertirlo en el caracter ascii correspondiente, eso lo vas concatenando en un string y para finalizar solo retornas la cadena.

```
string intToString(unsigned int number){
    string sNumber="";
    if(number==0)return "0";
    while(number>0){
        int digit=number%10;
        sNumber=(char)(digit+0x30)+sNumber;
        number=number/10;
    }
    return sNumber;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int number=984567;
    string result=intToString(number);
    cout<<result<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Cabe aclarar que este codigo solo aplica para numeros enteros sin signo.

Comment: Te ha faltado añadir `using namespace std`

Answer (score 2):

Este codigo es muy similar al de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63513/hacer-un-programa-que-pase-de-int-a-string/63517?noredirect=1#63517).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  bool negativo = false;

  int numero = 3458;
  string numero_string;

  if (numero < 0){

    negativo = true;
    numero =-numero;
  }


  if (numero == 0){
     numero_string = "0";
  }

  for(numero_string = ""; numero > 0; numero_string.insert(numero_string.begin(), numero %10+'0'), numero /=10);

  if (negativo){
      numero_string.insert(numero_string.begin(), '-');
  }

  std::cout << numero_string;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El proceso para pasar un número a cadena consiste en obtener el número dígito a dígito y guardar ese dígito en la cadena; para ello:

1. Obtenemos el residuo de la división del número entre su base numérica.
2. El residuo será el dígito, que pasaremos a carácter.
3. Dividimos el número por su base numérica.
4. Si el número no es 0, volvemos al punto 1.

El problema del proceso descrito es que nos genera el número en orden inverso (obtenemos primero los dígitos de menor peso), pero es fácil de resolver con recursividad:

```
void resuelve(int numero, int base, std::string &cadena)
{
    if (numero)
    {
        resuelve(numero / base, base, cadena);
        std::string::value_type c = numero % base;

        if (c >= 0 && c <= 9)
            c += '0';
        else if (c >= 10 && c <= 36)
            (c -= 10) += 'A';

        cadena.append(1, c);
    }
}

std::string numero_a_cadena(int numero, int base)
{
    std::string resultado{};
    resuelve(numero, base, resultado);
    return resultado;
}
```

La función `resuelve` es una función recursiva que *salta* hasta el dígito más significativo y lo añade a la cadena facilitada como tercer parámetro, acto seguido continúa con la recursión añadiendo los dígitos menos significativos hasta volver a la llamada original, estos serían unos ejemplos de uso:

```
std::cout << numero_a_cadena(51966, 2) << '\n';  // Muestra 1100101011111110
std::cout << numero_a_cadena(51966, 8) << '\n';  // Muestra 145376
std::cout << numero_a_cadena(51966, 10) << '\n'; // Muestra 51966
std::cout << numero_a_cadena(51966, 16) << '\n'; // Muestra CAFE
std::cout << numero_a_cadena(51966, 32) << '\n'; // Muestra 1INU
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sAddhOYiB9rBwdrg)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Implementación en Ansi-C.*/

void  intToChar2(int num, int base,char *storage, int *cont ){
    if(num < base){ 
        storage[*cont] = num + '0';        
        *cont++;
    }  
    else{
        intToChar2(num/base,base,storage,cont);
        (*cont) = (*cont)+1;
        storage[*cont] = (num%base) + '0';
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int numero;
    char *str1 = (char*) malloc(25);
    int cont = 0;
    printf("Escribe un número positivo:");
    scanf("%d",&numero);
    //intToChar1(numero,10,str1,&cont);
    intToChar2(numero,10,str1,&cont);
    printf("el número %d a cadena es: %s",cont,str1);
    return 0;
}
```